# Gensim Pickle Error: Enable to Load the Saved Topic Model

Tags: pickle, gensim, lda

I am working on topic inference that will require to load a previously saved model.

However, I got a pickle error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "topic_inference.py", line 35, in <module>
    model_for_inference = gensim.models.LdaModel.load(model_name, mmap = 'r')
  File "topic_modeling/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 1663, in load
    result = super(LdaModel, cls).load(fname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "topic_modeling/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 486, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)
  File "topic_modeling/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1461, in unpickle
    return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')  # needed because loading from S3 doesn't support readline()
TypeError: __randomstate_ctor() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

The code I use to load the model is simply

```
gensim.models.LdaModel.load(model_name, mmap = 'r')
```

Here is the code that I use to create and save the model

```
 model = gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore(
        corpus=comment_corpus,
        id2word=key_word_dict, ## This is now a gensim.corpora.Dictionary Object, previously it was the .id2token attribute
        chunksize=chunksize,
        alpha='symmetric',
        eta='auto',
        iterations=iterations,
        num_topics=num_topics,
        passes=epochs,
        eval_every=eval_every, 
        workers = 15,
        minimum_probability= 0.0)

model.save(output_model)
```

where `output_model` doesn't have an extension like `.model` or `.pkl`

In the past, I tried the similar approach with the exception that I passed in a `.id2token` attribute under the `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` object instead of the full `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` to the `id2word` parameter when I created the model, and the method loads the model fine back then. I wonder if passing in a `corpora.Dictionary` will make a difference in the loading output...? Back that time, I was using regular python, but now I am using anaconda. However, all the versions of the packages are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another report of an error about `__randomstate_ctor` (at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14210) suggests the problem may be related to numpy object pickling.

Is there a chance that the configuration where your load is failing is using a later version of `numpy` than when the save occurred? Could you try, at least temporarily, rolling back to some older `numpy` (that's still sufficient for whatever Gensim you're using) to see if it helps?

If you find any load that works, even in a suboptimal config, you might be able to null-out whatever `random`-related objects are causing the problem and re-save, then having a saved version that loads better in your truly-desired configuration. Then, if the `random`-related objects truly needed after reload, it may be possible to manually re-constitute them. (I haven't looked into this yet, but if you find any workaround allowing a load, but then aren't sure what to manually null/rebuild, I could take a closer look.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have figured out the problem: It seems that my numpy that is used to save the model is a later version (1.24.1) of the one that I am working for the inference (1.23.4). I updated `numpy` for my local inference code to 1.24.2 and it seems that the loading is working fine